# Beamer \renewcommand not working on \title

Tags: beamer, macros, titles

I am using `\titlepage` in my beamer presentation in the following way:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\title{FirstTitel}
\subtitel{FirstSubtitel}
\author{SomeName}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
...
```

Now I would like to define another frame containing the titlepage but with a different title. I tried:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \renewcommand{\title}{SecondTitle}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

and also

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \addto\captionsenglish{%
        \renewcommand{\title}{SecondTitle}
    }
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

but neither of these ideas worked. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call `\title` again to overwrite the information.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\title{FirstTitel}
\author{SomeName}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\title{Second Titel}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```